# Why won't my processes join in python?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pipe, zeromq

### Question edited to remove other bugs

---

I have a program which will not join once the processes are finished. How can I get it to join correctly?

```
import time
import sys
import zmq
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def client(address, pipe_send):
    try:
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO,5000)
        socket.connect(address)
        print("client connected")    
        while True:
            msg = str(pipe_send.recv())
            print("CLIENT $$",msg)
            if msg:
                socket.send_unicode(msg)
                recv_msg = socket.recv_unicode()
                print("CLIENT ::", recv_msg)
            else:
                break
    except:
        print(
            "client exited with '%s' while multiprocessing" 
            % (sys.exc_info(),)
        )
        
def server(address):
    try:
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO,5000)
        socket.bind(address)
        while True:
            try:
                msg = socket.recv_unicode()
                print("SERVER ::",msg)
                socket.send_unicode("Message sent successfully")
                time.sleep(1)
            except:
                break
    except:
        print(
            "server exited with '%s' while multiprocessing" 
            % (sys.exc_info(),)
        )
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    req_pipe, rep_pipe = Pipe()
    addr = "tcp://127.0.0.1:1235"
    s = Process(target=server,args=(addr,))
    s.start()
    c = Process(target=client,args=(addr,rep_pipe))
    c.start()
    for i in range(10):
        req_pipe.send(i)
    
    s.join()
    c.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't assign `Proces(..).start()` to `s`/`c`.
- Send sentinel value to notify end of data. I used `''`.

---

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    req_pipe, rep_pipe = Pipe()
    addr = "tcp://127.0.0.1:1235"
    s = Process(target=server,args=(addr,))
    s.start()
    c = Process(target=client,args=(addr,rep_pipe))
    c.start()
    for i in range(10):
        req_pipe.send(i)
    req_pipe.send('') # End of data.

    c.join()
    s.join()
```

Comment: why does sending '' through the pipe end up joining the process?

Comment: @user1876508, Because your `client` function expect that.

Comment: I did not know that '' was equivalent to nothing in if statements

Comment: @user1876508, empty string, empty list, empty tuple, dict, set, ... are treated as False if they are used as predicates.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = Process(target=server,args=(addr,)).start()
```

You have defined s to be the returned value of `start()`, instead of the `Process` itself, and the return value of `start()` must be `None`, which doesn't have a join method.

Comment: That fixed the traceback error, but now the processes won't join. I changed my code above in an attempt to fix this, but it did not help.